# Taking variable number of elements from list

Tags: haskell, lambda

I want to create one function that returns a list of all possible ways of splitting a list into two non-empty parts.

```
split :: [([a], [a])]
```

For example:

```
> split [1,2,3,4]

> [ ([1], [2,3,4]), ([1,2], [3,4]), ([1,2,3], [4]) ]
```

I'm far away from the solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's easy using `map`, `splitAt` and `flip`.

First do `import Data.List`

```
let split x = map (flip splitAt x) [1..length x-1]
```

result:

```
split [1,2,3,4]
[([1],[2,3,4]),([1,2],[3,4]),([1,2,3],[4])]
```

Explanation of flip - We are using `map` and `flip` to generate results in this example

```
[splitAt 1 x, splitAt 2 x, splitAt 3 x]
```

Flip simply allows us to flip the expected arguments. Otherwise we could have written a lambda like so:

```
let split x = map (\z -> splitAt z x) [1..length x-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think at this fast solution! Thanks again!

Comment: You can also use infix splitAt instead of `flip splitAt x`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another approach using `inits` and `tails`:

Let xs = [1,2,3,4]. Note:

```
import Data.List

inits xs -- returns: [[]       ,     [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
tails xs -- returns: [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4]    , []]
```

So zipping these two lists together give you all the ways of splitting the list into two parts:

```
zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
  = [ ([], [1,2,3,4]),
      ([1], [2,3,4] ),
      ([1,2], [3,4]) ,
      ([1,2,3,4], []) ]
```

If you don't want the first and last pairs, just trim appropriately:

```
split xs = init $ tail $ zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Comment: It might be nice to mention that doing something similar with `Data.Sequence` is surprisingly time and space efficient, thanks to Louis Wasserman's brilliant `inits` and `tails` implementations and to a lesser extent to my own `zip`/`zipWith` implementation.

Comment: @dfeuer why is it **surprisingly** time and space efficient - I thought `Data.Sequence` would be an ideal fit for this kind of problem.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, I continue to be impressed by its `inits` and `tails`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to implement this yourself **not** using library functions

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splits [] = []
splits xx = splits' ([],xx)
  where splits' :: ([a],[a]) -> [([a],[a])]
        splits' xy@(x,[]) = [xy]
        splits' xy@(x,y:yy) = let z = (x++[y],yy)
                              in xy:splits' z
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach with iterate

```
split (x:xs) = takeWhile (not . null . snd) $ iterate (\(x,(y:ys)) -> (x++[y],ys)) ([x], xs)
```